# An expression / a proverb to say: "liars often forget what they said"

Tags: idioms, expressions, proverbs

As you may confronted some liars, you possibly would confirm that usually they forget what they have made-up and then related to you in the past and it's not unlekely that once they will forget in the future what they cited in the past.

I need an expression or possibly a proverb to explain the fact that usually all liars **have a weak memory**.

**Example:**

> A) I tell you I couldn’t have done the murder, because I was up in London when it happened. 
>   B) Which part of London? 
>   A) Battersea. 
>   B) Last time when I asked you, you said it was Bermondsey. Come on, let’s have the truth for a change. [**The needed expression/proverb should come here.**]

The only proverbial sentence I heard is:

> All liar ought to have a good memory!

but I have no idea whether it works in current English or it's a Shakespearian wording of the statement in my question or what! Please let me know about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"No man has a good enough memory to be a successful liar" - Abe Lincoln

[Explaination of this from Yahoo answers](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080206142143AAMosQ6&guccounter=1&guce_referrer=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8&guce_referrer_sig=AQAAAEn6clgTHPbUtikBdkBt-vO-mgUltkNkYNiOS-7aOUXPzVZkiOVSQc24I_C65zOX7-T4LJhaqLkWybuuC6V1jmPS1kLmZmEQZ_1mm4kLMcqEaA2kVG6CpuGY3lFMNtkT211o6i0DjGmsupldojzZXbxTu7mxDu5mhNbHR7-Ak2Rp)

Mark Twain also said that you should tell the truth because you won’t have to remember anything.

[Forbes](https://www.forbes.com/quotes/68/) has a good selection of other quotes and idioms.